# How to create a certain function with a for loop to add number as separate property

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to all this.

Create a function called countingArray that takes in an array and a number as arguments. The function should then:

1. Use a loop to count up to the number passed in
2. Add each number in the loop to the array as a separate property
3. Return the array

Then call the function with the provided empty array and number variable.

My code:

```
var emptyArray = [];
var number = 17;

function countingArray(array,num){
  for (i=0;i<=array.length;i++){
  }
  return array;
}
countingArray(emptyArray,number);
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your question?

Comment: `array.push(/*guess this ;) */)` ...

Comment: add to the array "as a separate property"?  You aren't supposed to just add the number to the array?

Comment: @JonasW. I suspect that OP really wants to add numbers 0/1-17 to the array.  They will need to change the termination clause too.

Comment: If you're a bit advanced, you could do: `const countingArray = (length, arr) => Array.from({length}, i => i);`

Comment: I'm assuming this is a homework assignment, so I'm not going to post an explicit answer, but:  "Add each number in the loop to the array as a separate property" is poorly worded;  I think they're trying to say 'push each number onto the array" without using the word "push" (because it's a clue to how to do it).

Comment: (Also, take another look at step 1: you shouldn't be looping to the length of the array, it should be to the number passed in.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear but the modified version of your code will count up to the number passed and place each increment into an array.

```
var emptyArray = [];
    var number = 17;

    function countingArray(array,num){
      for (i=0;i<=number;i++){
      array.push(i)
    }
      return array;
    }
    countingArray(emptyArray,number);
```

Comment: `/*spoiler alert!*/`

Comment: What an earth is a spoiler alert?

Comment: This is pretty clearly  a homework assignment, and you (and the other answer right after yours) both just gave away the answer.

Comment: Sorry I thought the idea was to assist in code issues not be judgmental as to what the purpose of the code is for.

Comment: From now on I will assume all questions need a cryptic answer *you could try array.push(something?)

Comment: No need to be snarky. [Opinions differ with respect to how to answer homework questions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: That was exactly my point why paste spoiler alert. My opinion was to help the op with there question not be sarcastic. But it seems people just like to add graffiti no sarcasm is meant from here.

Comment: That's what "community moderated" means, and afaik it's why we have comment threads in the first place.  I tend to agree with the opinion that just doing someone's homework for them isn't the best way to help them, and thought Jonas's comment was a (rather lighthearted) way of saying that, not "graffiti". But, like I said, opinions differ.

Answer (score 0):

You could

- define all variables inside of the function,
- use `number` for checking the upper bound of the for loop,
- push the value of `i` to the array.

```js
function countingArray(array, num) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
        array.push(i);
    }
    return array;
}

var emptyArray = [],
    number = 17;

console.log(countingArray(emptyArray, number));
```